# Reverse proxy nginx to application

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, synology

I have a synology and I want to link a subdomain to one of this application. This is the URL I usually use to access to this service:

> 192.168.0.17:5001//index.cgi?launchApp=SYNO.SDS.App.FileStation3.Instance&launchParam=openfile%3D%252FOliver%252F

But this is too long and I want to access it directly this mydomaine.com

How should I configure the server ?

I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    resolver 89.2.0.1;

    server_name test.fr;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header        Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;
        proxy_http_version      1.1;

        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.17:5000/index.cgi?launchApp=SYNO.SDS.App.FileStation3.Instance&launchParam=openfile%3D%252FOliver%252F;

    }

}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: When you say doesn't work, what does that mean?

Comment: I can't see the final application on the web page. It just doesn't load the final application. I just see a blank page.

Comment: Check in Chrome developer tools, network tab and see what you see if see any 404s or anything?

Comment: The only code I get is 200.

Comment: Try removing all `proxy_set_header`

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: Just keep proxy_pass for now. And use it like this `set $proxy_pass_url "http://192.168.0.17:5000/index.cgi?launchApp=SYNO.SDS.App.FileStation3.Instance&launchParam=openfile%3D%252FOliver%252F";` and then `proxy_pass $proxy_pass_url;`

Comment: I have again the same result. Thank you for the time you spend for me!

Comment: You need to debug then what is wrong. See this article on how to debug a reverse proxy http://tarunlalwani.com/post/how-to-debug-nginx-reverse-proxy-issues-php-fpm-gunicorn-uwsgi/

Comment: OK, maybe I want something impossible...
An other acceptable way is to convert  `test.fr` into `test.fr/index.cgi?launchApp=SYNO.SDS.App.F‌​ileStation3.Instance‌​&launchParam=openfil‌​e%3D%252FOliver%252F‌​` and then only redirect `test.fr` to `192.168.0.17:5000` but I don't know how to do that...

Comment: Right now a simple proxy_pass is not working so you need debug why, then only this could work

Comment: I can't right now test my config and put error log. I'll do that next week. But right now, I test proxy `test.fr` to `192.168.0.17:5000` and it worked... but without the application I want to call

Comment: Other problem I have, it not a dedicated device, it's a synology, which doesn't come with Socat. Is there an other tool to do the job ?

Comment: You need socat on the nginx machine and not on the proxied server

Comment: they are the same machine. The synology hosts nginx and the services I want to access to

Comment: I have no idea then

Comment: OK. Thanks for your help. One thing more, could you tell me how to configure the server so that `test.fr` is rewritten into `test.fr/index.cgi?launchApp=SYNO.SDS.App.F‌​ileStation3.Inst‌​ance‌​&launchParam=o‌​penfil‌​e%3D%252FOli‌​ver%252F‌`​ and redirect `test.fr` to `192.168.0.17:5000` ?